# Unhandled ''error'' event in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to active an RFID reader through node.js and then send the tag back.

It works great. It reads the tag, responds with an ID, then send the ID to the pinging node client.

However, every time the node.JS program picks up a set of data from an RFID tag, after it sends, it closes down with the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EBADF, read
```

This causes the node process to quit all the time. What could be the problem here?

My code is the following;

```
// Socket.io server details
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);
// Serialport plugin declared and made a serialport variable
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
// Variable containing technical USB port details
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", 
 {baudrate: 2400, parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")},
 false); // this is the openImmediately flag [default is true]



io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

 console.log('user connected');

 socket.on('ping', function (data) {

 serialPort.open(function () {

 // Open notification
 console.log('open');

 //Start listening
 serialPort.on('data', function(data) {


 // If content is empty, filter out
 if (data.trim() !== '') {
 line = data;

 //Execute function again, get tag, handle tag and end process
 serialPort.close(function () {
 console.log('De uiteindelijke tag is ' + data);
 console.log('Ping received with data: ' + data);
 socket.emit('pong', data);
 console.log('closing');
 });
 console.log('hallo');
 }
 });
 });


 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to handle the error in the serial port, like the code below:

```
serialPort.on('error', function(error) {
   console.log('The error: '+error);
   //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It catches the error but the app does get closed. How so?

Comment: Just says ''Aborted'' after your console.log input now.

Comment: what is the error that it prints in the console.log?

Comment: ok, I dont know the reason for this error... but you can use the package https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever to start your script, it will keep running even if an error happens in the script

Comment: @MichaelP I just noticed one weird thing in your code, why do you invoke the 'serialPort.close' function inside the on data listener?

Comment: I want the serial connection to close after one line of data